# How to print large number in c?

Tags: c, bigint

I tried to solve **problem set 16** in **projecteuler.net**. I am trying to find `2^1000` for which I had written a code in C with a function named `power()`.The problem here is that if i place `printf()` inside `power()` to get the result value, the answer is `10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376.000000` but if I use return value in `power()` and try to print the result from `main()` the answer is `-2147483648.000000`.
here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(double base,int ex)
{
    int i = 1;
    double final = 0;
    double ans = 1;
    while (i <= ex){
        ans *= base;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%lf\n",ans);     // return ans;
}


int main()
{
    double num;
    double result;
    int power_value;
    printf("enter the base value\n");
    scanf("%lf",&num);
    printf("enter the exponent value\n");
    scanf("%d",&power_value);
    power(num,power_value); //result = power(num,power_value)
    //printf("%lf",result);
}
```

Comment: c is not c++ and `double main()` is certainly not c++

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. If you program in C and want a solution in C then use only that tag.

Comment: As for your problem, you should do more research about [the standard types and their ranges](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types). And try to find a *bignum* library if you want anything outside the possibilities of the standard types.

Comment: The idea of this projecteuler question is to find a way to calculate the sum of the digits of `2^1000` without calculating `2^1000`, since (as all the others mentioned) it does not fit into a common datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that a different gets printed inside `power` as opposed to `main` is because the return type of `power` is `int`.  As a result, the value gets truncated to what will fit in an `int`.

Change the return type to `double` so that it matches the type of the variables you're using and you'll get the expected result.

```
double power(double base,int ex)
```

As others have mentioned, numbers this large are outside the range of an `int`, and *most* numbers this size can't be accurately represented in a `double`.  In this particular case however, because the number you're calculating is a power of two it *can* be represented exactly.  Had you chosen a base besides 2 (or a power of 2), the result would not be exact.

Answer (score 2):

The number you want to calculate is actually much greater than standard types in C can handle. `long` on todays machines has almost always a width of 64 bits, so the maximum number that can be stored in it is something like **2^64** = 18.446.744.073.709.551.615 < 2^2000

Also you can't start a program with `double main() { }`. Specification requires you to use `int` or `void`.

You'll have to find some library that does that calculation for you.